# Unecessary indent error in visual studio using python

Tags: python, visual-studio

Recently i have started practicing python with visual studio. Yet when i run this simple script [see below] VS gives me an indent error on the first line. While if i were to use this script in my CMD or Spyder it works perfectly fine. Any suggestions to solve this problem in VS? (SOLVED)

```
blockchain =[] 
def add_value():
    blockchain.append(8.0,19.3)
    print(blockchain)
add_value()
```

Comment: Doubt it works fine since `appen` is not valid. Never-the-less, you will need to configure VS with a Python addon/plugin to have it recognize the formatting correctly.

Comment: i have used the tabs and spaces correct as in spyder and in my CMD the script works perfectly. I also have installed a python plug in for VS. Although this is my first script in VS i am sure that the syntax is correct(i couldnt post an image so i had to try type the script over in the post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code

```
// change this
blockchain.appen(8.0,19.3)
// to this
blockchain.append(8.0,19.3)
```

The code is then valid.

VSCode doesn't throw me any indentation error for that. Check that you're using tabs for all your indentations.

Comment: Sorry i have typed it over wrong but i indeed have it exactly as you have written it. Yet i get an unexpected indent in the first line which i find strange

Comment: try restarting VS

Comment: I also noticed you have a trailing whitespace at the end of the first line, how about you remove it? It might be the cause of the error

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and indeed you are right. but when i restart my VS there is still no difference. This is the first ever script i have written with VS and also i have downloaded the python plug in, so that shouldnt be the problem either. And im sure the syntax is correct because in my CMD it runs perfectly fine aswell as in Spyder. Do you maybe have any other suggestions?

Comment: Your code is valid, don't worry - VS and VSCode are ver powerful but quite buggy sometimes... At this point I have no suggestion but to change variable names or reinstall the software

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Visual Studio

```
Tools -> Option -> Text Editor -> Python -> Tabs
```

- Disable the "Keep the Tabs"
- Select "Insert Spaces"
- Select "Indenting" as "Smart"